# litteral string is not displayed (osdev)

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, x86-64

I am currently developping a small OS for educationnal puprose (and because this is fun). I am succesfully passing in 64-bit mode and I jump on a c-function "kmain" to program with a higer level language. Everything is set up (cross compiler, disk read to load my c function on the second sector at address 0x7e00 ...). The following code work perfectly :

```c
#define VIDEO_MEMORY_LOCATION 0xb8000

void kmain() {

    char msg[] = "Hello world!";
    int i =0;
    char *video_memory = (char *)VIDEO_MEMORY_LOCATION;

    while (msg[i]) {
        *video_memory = msg[i];
        i++;
        video_memory += 2;
    }
}
```

my string is correctly displayed. However, I am trying to have a string located in rodata like this :

```c
#define VIDEO_MEMORY_LOCATION 0xb8000

void kmain() {

    char *msg = "Hello world!";
    char *video_memory = (char *)VIDEO_MEMORY_LOCATION;

    while (*msg) {
        *video_memory = *msg;
        msg++;
        video_memory += 2;
    }
}
```

and it dosen't work. To be more precise, I have the same screen as before but the string is not displayed. It does not crash too. Just the string is not here. One of my first thought is : "The .rodata is incorrectly loaded, and therefor my string is not in my executable", but I am sure this is not this, here why :
When I dissasemble :

```
00000200  55                push rbp
00000201  4889E5            mov rbp,rsp
00000204  48C745F845FE0000  mov qword [rbp-0x8],0xfe45
0000020C  48C745F000800B00  mov qword [rbp-0x10],0xb8000
00000214  EB17              jmp short 0x22d
00000216  488B45F8          mov rax,[rbp-0x8]
0000021A  0FB610            movzx edx,byte [rax]
0000021D  488B45F0          mov rax,[rbp-0x10]
00000221  8810              mov [rax],dl
00000223  488345F801        add qword [rbp-0x8],byte +0x1
00000228  488345F002        add qword [rbp-0x10],byte +0x2
0000022D  488B45F8          mov rax,[rbp-0x8]
00000231  0FB600            movzx eax,byte [rax]
00000234  84C0              test al,al
00000236  75DE              jnz 0x216
00000238  90                nop
00000239  90                nop
0000023A  5D                pop rbp
0000023B  C3                ret
0000023C  0F1F4000          nop dword [rax+0x0]
00000240  E8BBFFFFFF        call 0x200
00000245  48                rex.w                           # not code, my "Hello world!" string located at 0xfe45
00000246  656C              gs insb
00000248  6C                insb
00000249  6F                outsd
0000024A  20776F            and [rdi+0x6f],dh
...
```

we wan see that my string is here and the addresse when we get the string is correct.
I can't understand why "Hello world!" is not displayed.

In qemu, when I display what is inside memory at address 0xfe45, i get :
(qemu) x/8c 0x7e45
000000000007e45: 'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' ' ' 'w' 'o' 'r' 'l' 'd' '!' '\0x00'

This kind of code :

```c
void kmain() {

    char *video_memory = (char *)VIDEO_MEMORY_LOCATION;
    char msg0[] = "AZE";
    int i = 0;

    while (msg0[i]) {
        *video_memory = msg0[i];
        i++;
        video_memory += 2;
    }

    char *msg = "Hello world!";

    while (*msg) {
        *video_memory = *msg;
        msg++;
        video_memory += 2;
    }
}
```

disaply "AZE" only.

**Edit :**
With the help of a debbuger (bochs with gui), i can stop on the instruction which load the first character of the string into rax :
[image: memory state before loading first character]
We can see that the content of rax is 0xfe45 as expected, the content of 0xfe45 is 0x48 ('H') as expected, so everything should be fine. But if I step to execute just one instruction, I can see that rax has 0 as content. I can't understand why.

I am not sure if it is necessary but here's how I compile :
(note that i put only the relevent target, ld and cc are cross-compiler to x86_64-pc-elf)

```
os.bin: bootloader/bootloader.bin kernel/kernel.bin # must be in correct order !
    cat $^ > $@

kernel/kernel.bin: kernel/kmain.o bootloader/kernel_entry.o
    ${LD} --oformat binary -Ttext 0xFe00 $^ -o $@

kernel/kmain.o: kernel/kmain.c
    ${CC} -m64 -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -Wall -g -c $^ -o $@
```

no linker script are used as I compile in binary format.

Comment: As a general tip, if you're going to debug assembly, it may actually be easier if you turn on optimizations.  With `-O0` you have to track values being needlessly moved to and from memory, when they could just stay in a register.

Comment: Look at that carefully again: the code is trying to read the string from address `0xfe45`, but since you loaded at base address `0x7e00` it is actually at `0x7e45`.  I don't think you've correctly informed your linker where to locate the code and data.  If you need help figuring that out, post your complete build command line, and linker scripts if any.

Comment: I add some information that can help I guess. We can see that the address are correct, just 0 is loaded in rax instead of 0x45 for a reason that I can't understand.

Comment: No, the address is not correct!  In the image you posted, the highlighted line of data is at address `0x7e40`, and the `H` is at `0x7e45`.  You are loading from address `0xfe45`.  Those are not the same!!  One starts with 7 and the other with F.  They are 32 Kbytes apart.

Comment: And so why did you put `-Ttext 0xFe00` on your link command line?  You are intending to load this code at address `0x7e00`, so writing `-Ttext 0x7e00` would make more sense.  (I am not sure if this guarantees that `.rodata` and other sections will be placed correctly also, but maybe they are in practice.)

Comment: You are right, I feel so stupid searching hours and hours and posting this just for the -Ttext mistake. I dont know why I put fe00 here when I correctly used 7e00 everywhere else. In format --binary there is no section anymore, everything is "packed" at one place, so this should be fine. (not sure about my last sentence but this seems right)

Comment: There certainly are sections in the input object files to the linker.  The purpose of the linker is to place the contents of those sections into the flat binary file, applying relocations as it does so.  So here we are making the assumption that it will choose to place the contents of `.rodata` after the contents of `.text`.  That does seem to be the default behavior, but I don't know if it is documented or guaranteed.  You could use the linker script to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> and it dosen't work.

There is absolutely *no difference* between your two loops as far as `C` is concerned.

Comment: there is a difference, the assembly generated is absolutely not the same. And maybe I forgot to say that I compile with -oformat binary, so there is no .rodata, .text ... and does not exist in binary format. Moreover, as I mentioned and as you can see in the assembly, my string is in the code generated and accessed at the correct address.

Comment: @VoxoR There is _no difference_ as far as `C` is concerned. The only other thing I can think of is that you are only initializing every other byte of the video memory (in either case) -- maybe that matters. Since you've already set up QEMU and debugger, step though the code to confirm that the right bytes are written to video memory by the `MOV` at `0x0221`

Comment: With the help of a debugger, I can see that the value of rax when it execute `00000231  0FB600            movzx eax,byte [rax]` is 0xFE45, and at this address there is the 'H' (0x48) but after the execution, eax contains 0 and therefore end immediately the loop. I have no idea why it load 0.